# PyGTK: IM Client Window

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to write something very similar to an IM client (for learning purposes only). I don't know how to write the Chat window. I want to display Users picture, name and message as any other IM client. The problem is that I don't know which gtk widget is best suited for it. Currently I use TextView and TextBuffers but I can't display Pictures and Links in the TextView. How does pidgin or empathy handle this?.

I'm using Glade with GtkBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display images in a gtk.TextBuffer, here is how: http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TextBuffers.html#id2855808